How to Use transform to Convert an @Input Array to an Object in Angular?
Can I use transform to have an @Input or InputSignal receive an array and transform it to an object containing the array?
Example:
<my-component
    [array]="myArray"
/>


export class MyComponent {
    public readonly array = input<number[]>([], {
            transform: transformArrayToObject,
        });

So if the value passed to array is [1, 2, 3], the transformed data will be, by example:
{
  array: [1, 2, 3];
  status: Status.OK
}


Transform is usually good for modifying a source type and returning the same type with manipulations to the inner values. If you want to create a new object, it's better to use computed which will create a new object based on the original signal. The computed signal will refresh whenever the source signal changes.
...
export class Child {
  public readonly value: InputSignal<any[]> = input<any[]>([]);
  public readonly computedValue = computed(() => ({
    status: Status.OK,
    data: this.value(),
  }));
}

Full Code:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, InputSignal, computed, input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export enum Status {
  OK,
}

export interface DataObject {
  status: number;
  data: any[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{computedValue() | json}}`,
})
export class Child {
  public readonly value: InputSignal<any[]> = input<any[]>([]);
  public readonly computedValue = computed(() => ({
    status: Status.OK,
    data: this.value(),
  }));
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child [value]="[1,2,3,4,100]"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
